# How do I scope variables properly in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm working on a jQuery plugin, but am having some trouble getting my variables properly scoped. Here's an example from my code:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.ksana = function(userOptions) {
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.ksana.defaultOptions, userOptions);

    return this.each(function() {
        alert(rotate()); // o is not defined
    });
};

function rotate() {
    return Math.round(o.negRot + (Math.random() * (o.posRot - o.negRot)));
};

$.fn.ksana.defaultOptions = {
    negRot: -20,
    posRot: 20
};

})(jQuery);
```

I'm trying to get the private function rotate to be able to see the o variable, but it just keeps alerting 'o is not defined'. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `o` variable is locally scoped inside the `$.fn.ksana` function, in order to allow the `rotate` to reach it, you should either:

- Simply pass the `o` variable to it as an argument.
- Define that function within `ksana`.
- Define `o` in the outer scope.

IMO, passing it as an argument is enough clean:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.ksana = function(userOptions) {
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.ksana.defaultOptions, userOptions);

    return this.each(function() {
        alert(rotate(o)); // pass o
    });
  };

  function rotate(o) { // use passed object
    return Math.round(o.negRot + (Math.random() * (o.posRot - o.negRot)));
  }
//...
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 Since you're not exposing `rotate` outside the plugin, may as well pass the variable in as an argument to avoid having unnecessary global state.

Comment: This may be a daft question, but doesn't that create additional overhead? I'm going to have a lot of functions that will need access to o, so I'd be passing o around a lot...

Comment: @safetycopy: Well, you can expose `o` to more functions, like I say in my third approach, defining `o` in the enclosing scope.

Comment: So, that would look like:

    `(function($) {
        var o = null;
        $.fn.ksana = function(userOptions) {
            o = $extend({}, $.fn.ksana.defaultOptions, userOptions);`

Is that correct?

Comment: @safetycopy: Right, by the way, you don't really need to assign `null` (unless you specifically want), if you don't assign anything, i.e. `var o;` o will contain `undefined`, also you [don't need semicolons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript) after function declarations (like `rotate` in your original post).

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I think I prefer the option of moving the rotate function to within `ksana`. Thanks for your input and the semicolons advice :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `o` in the scope that is surrounding for both `rotate` and `ksana` - i.e. in your root `function($)` scope. Like this:

```
(function($) {

var o;

$.fn.ksana = function(userOptions) {
   o = $.extend({}, $.fn.ksana.defaultOptions, userOptions);
```

But why don't you just make it an argument of `rotate`? Why do you need to make it kind of "global"?

Comment: o is merged from the user and default options. If it's in the root function's scope, I don't think I'd be able to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

You can either put the rotate-function in the same scope as o:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.ksana = function(userOptions) {
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.ksana.defaultOptions, userOptions);

    function rotate() {
        return Math.round(o.negRot + (Math.random() * (o.posRot - o.negRot)));
    };

    return this.each(function() {
        alert(rotate()); 
    });
};
```

Or, simply pass it to rotate:

```
(function($) {

    var o;
    $.fn.ksana = function(userOptions) {
        o = $.extend({}, $.fn.ksana.defaultOptions, userOptions);

        return this.each(function() {
           alert(rotate(o)); 
        });
    };

function rotate(o) {
    return Math.round(o.negRot + (Math.random() * (o.posRot - o.negRot)));
};
```

Comment: Would moving the rotate function to the same scope as o keep rotate private?