# How to handle click event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture

Today is my first day at a new job (a Front End Lead on a large website.)  One of my tasks is to implement a button that fires an event when it's clicked.  I had no clue, so after googling a bit, I came up with this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup(); 
{
    alert("Hello World") ==> alert("Hello World");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="popup()"></input><br></br>

</html>    
</body>
```

The problem is, when I click my button, nothing happens.

**EDIT** Updated based on MICHEL's comments

Comment: syntax error `function popup()
{
    alert("Hello World");
}`

Comment: You may be interested in a series that I'm writing about jQuery's event system and discusses browser event models - http://forloop.co.uk/event-internals-in-jquery-part-one

Comment: Front End Lead on a large website? o_O I greatly encourage you to learn jQuery as soon as possible.

Comment: I want to know where this guy works, maybe they will hire my daughter ;-)

Comment: `alert("Hello World") ==> alert("Hello World");` is not a valid statement.

Comment: @RichardFriend Hmm.... A large website with bare JavaScript in HTML and great colleagues.... difficult to get in and even more difficult to deliver work and be happy with yourself....

Comment: There's a semicolon after "function popup()" which makes popup a null function.  The block that is after it is no longer the body of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function popup() 
{
    alert("Hello World");
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="popup()"><br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is now pasted into our project!

Answer (score 6):

remove the semi-colon:

```
function popup()
{
    alert("Hello World")
}
```

that should work ^_^

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/fNeJh/

Comment: Where should I put the semicolon then?

Comment: nowhere lol. do what i did above. there is no need for semicolons (you can use them if you want. put it after alert like: `alert("Hello World");`)

Comment: I would advise those learning JavaScript to **not** leave off semicolons.

Comment: @Pointy , true, as i said, they are not needed, but you can use them, just at the end of lines, not function creating

Comment: I'm with @Pointy ;) Also, put a semicolon after a function expression: `var foo = function () {};`. Better yet, use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML is invalid. Change

```
</html>    
</body>
```

to

```
</body>
</html>
```

Also, the `<br>` tag has no content, so you don't need a closing tag at all (for HTML) or you can write it as a self-closing tag: `<br/>`.

As far as the JavaScript error goes, Neal's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remove semi-colon after

Bad :

```
function popup();
```

Good :

```
function popup()
```

You might want to add one after  alert("Hello World") ==>  alert("Hello World");

Comment: `alert("Hello World") ==> alert("Hello World");` is not a valid statement.

Comment: What do you mean?
I ment to replace 
alert("Hello World")
by : 
alert("Hello World");

Comment: I meant that `alert("Hello World") ==> alert("Hello World");` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

function should not have a semi colon after its declaration ... A simple tutorial on javascript would give you a start on javascript...

Comment: This is a kind of simple mistake not always easy to see... even from more experienced ones...

Comment: It's a common practice to put a semicolon at the end of a function declaration because not doing so might have an undesired effect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript .