# Missing semicolon breaks script unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, function, closures, undefined

*NOTE: originally, I thought the issue was caused by something more complex; I see now (and edited the title and sample code) that the only difference is the presence or absence of a semicolon.  That may make this a no-brainer to answer, but I was still surprised to see a trailing semicolon matters in this case and not others...*

Why does this work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.someFunc = function () {};
    (function () {
        console.log("self-invoking function called.")
    })();
</script>
```

but this does not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.someFunc = function () {}

    (function () {
        console.log("self-invoking function called.")
    })();
</script>
```

and yet, this does:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.someFunc = function () {}
    var someVar = "value";
    console.log("someVar is:"+someVar);
</script>
```

The latter interprets the self-invoking function as `undefined`, and therefore cannot evaluate/execute it.  Tested on Chrome 13, Firefox 6, and Safari 5 on OSX.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for semicolon after every function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript)

Comment: yes, i think so.  sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the first Related topic on the right of your question: [Why should I use a semicolon after every function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript)

The accepted answer is a great explanation of this behavior.

Comment: oof.  the semicolon-related posts didn't come up as related until after i posted this, since my post didn't even address semicolons until i figured that part out...right before i posted it.  sorry to duplicate.  i'll choose this answer once the 5-minute time minimum time is up...

Comment: and nice to see you this side of the processing forums, philho!

Comment: Well, I wasn't aware of the issue, so thanks for pointing it out... And the explanation of @InvisibleBacon is detailed and somehow clearer than the one I point to (which is good, still), so I suggest to give him the accepted answer, mine is more a pointer than a real answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the second snippet is actually executing the empty function declaration. If you change your example to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.someFunc = function (arg) { console.log(arg); }

    (function () {
        console.log("self-invoking function called.")
    })();
</script>
```

and then run (FF6), you will see that it logs: `function()`. It's passing in the second anonymous function as an argument for the first. This makes more sense if you rearrange:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.someFunc = function (arg) { console.log(arg); }(
        function () {
        console.log("self-invoking function called.")
    })

    (); //the parser doesn't know what to do with this line.
</script>
```

Comment: yep, makes sense, and is in line with the other leading question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript).  thx bacon.