# Why if / elseif statement not working jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click

Sorry if this is a repeat but couldnt find anything the same ish...

I can't get the if else statement to work. I get the first part done but the second won't.
The aim is to click on a div and it expands, then when clicked again it shrinks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".back2").css("height") < "51px")
    {
        $(".back2").click(function()
        {
            $(".back2_img,.back2").css({"height":"200px"}, 'slow'); 
        });
    }
    ElseIf($(".back2").css("height") >"55px")
    {
        $(".back2").click(function()
        {
            $(".back2,.back2_img").css({"height":"50px"}, 'slow');
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tidied up your code, also it is `else if` not `ElseIf`.
You also had a slight syntax problem with one of your `;`. (Not necessarily a code breaking error, but just a good habit to keep things 100% consistent, see comments for more info).

Proper nesting of code will save you hours of headache!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".back2").css("height") < "51px") {
        $(".back2").click(function() {
            $(".back2_img,.back2").css({
                "height": "200px"
            }, 'slow');
        });
    }
    else if($(".back2").css("height") > "55px") {
        $(".back2").click(function() {
            $(".back2,.back2_img").css({
                "height": "50px"
            }, 'slow');
        });
    }
});​
```

Comment: Also the comparison using the greater than and less than against a string won't work as expected. ie. "140px" > "55px" = false

Comment: `;`s are not required, nor is it a syntax error to place it where the user had.  [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript).

Comment: ";s are not required" - my point exactly, why have something that is un-needed? - Keep semi-colons for specifically denoting code end points, to save yourself confusion. Plus JS validators will throw up an error anyway, so may as well fix them.

Comment: @AlexanderWigmore Touche.  I wish I could expand, but there isn't that much else to say.  You make a fine point.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is `else if`:

```js
if (condition) {
    //code
}
else if (condition) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's "else if" not "ElseIf", javascript is a case-sensitive language. And please write in nested-style! for God sake... Please, it's good for you AND everyone else. Like this:

```
$(document)
.ready(
    function(){
        if ($(".back2").css("height") < "51px")
        {
            $(".back2")
            .click(
                function()
                {
                    $(".back2_img,.back2")
                    .css(
                        {"height":"200px"}, 
                        'slow'
                    );
                }
            );
        }
        else if ($(".back2").css("height") >"55px") {
            $(".back2")
            .click(
                function()
                {
                    $(".back2,.back2_img")
                    .css(
                        {"height":"50px"}, 
                        'slow'
                    );
                }
            );
         };
    }
);
```