# Javascript undefined class function when missing semicolon

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo() {
    var that = this;
    that.bar = function() {}
    that.baz = function() {}

    (function() {
        that.baz();
    }());
}
new Foo;
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Foo> has no method 'baz'`

`that.bar` works fine, it's only the last function that doesn't exist. Adding a `;` after the `baz` function definition fixes everything.

I know excluding `;` can mess some things up, but I thought for sure you're not supposed to put `;` after functions. No language does that. Why does excluding the `;` after the `baz` function cause this to break? Should I be putting `;` after my function definitions?

Comment: Note: `that.baz` is not a function, it is "property" of `that`. Most semicolon languages require `;` in such cases...

Comment: It's nicer to use `!function() {...}()` for immediately invoking functions, since it avoids such issues. That said, one rule to keep in mind, if you ever start a new line with `(` or `[`, just put a semicolon before it... `;(...` `;[...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a semicolon after a function declaration:

```
function foo() {
}
```

There is no harm done if you do add a semicolon, you just don't need it:

```
function foo() {
};
```

That inserts an empty statement after your function declaration, which has no effect. In the same way, this would do no harm, other than confusing people who read your code:

```
var i = 1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

OTOH, you *do* need a semicolon after an assignment statement:

```
that.prop = 1;
```

and that doesn't change if the value you're assigning is a function expression:

```
that.foo = function() {};
```

Comment: No you do not **need** a semicolon after an assignment statement. They're **needed** in very few cases. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/ . Consistency should be encouraged though

Comment: Thank you. This was less obvious when my functions contained code and spanned multiple lines. putting `;` at the end looks wrong. Maybe I'll use the other type of function definition.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar As for different definitions for functions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: @Ian - that's an excellent point. JavaScript will insert semicolons for you in many cases. OTOH, the grammar for [a function declaration does not require a semicolon at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript) - JavaScript doesn't even bother inserting one, so it's not even a question of automatic semicolon insertion. It does insert one for you when you leave it out in the other cases, so it really is a bit of a different situation.

Answer (score 10):

Contrary to [Michael Geary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533873), assignment statements ***do not*** require semicolons.

Consider the humble immediately-invoked function expression:

```
(function() { /* do something */ })();
```

What are the extra parentheses wrapping the `function() { ... }` for? They're to prevent it from being interpreted as a function *definition*, forcing it to be interpreted as a function expression. It's basically equivalent to this, but without creating another variable:

```
var temp = function() { /* do something */ };
temp();
```

But parentheses are only one way to introduce something that must be an expression. In particular, **an initializer of an assignment statement will introduce an expression**<sup>1</sup>:

```
someVar = /* what goes here must be an expression */;
```

Clearly, composing these concepts shows that in this:

```
someVar = (function() { return 5; })();
```

The wrapping parentheses are not actually needed! We could just as easily write this because the `function()` cannot be interpreted as a function definition:

```
someVar = function() { return 5; } ();
```

So what does this have to do with semicolons? It turns out that if the next line can continue the statement or expression, it will.<sup>2</sup> You've written this:

```
that.baz = function() {}

(function() {
    that.baz();
}());
```

With this knowledge, you know it's actually being interpreted as this:

```
that.baz = (function() {})(function() {
    that.baz();
}());
```

That's a bit tricky, so here's what's happening:

1. First, `function() {}` is evaluated (*not* executed), yielding a function object.
2. This function object is then called, *but wait*! It has some arguments we have to evaluate before we can begin executing it proper.
3. The only argument is the expression

   ```
   function() {
       that.baz();
   }()
   ```

   That's obviously an immediately-invoked function expression, so we'll begin executing it.
4. We try to find `that.baz` and call it, but it fails because `that.baz` does not exist and thus resolves to `undefined`! Oh no! **The JavaScript engine stops here because an uncaught exception was thrown, but for clarity, let's pretend it went on.**
5. We never returned anything from `function() { that.baz(); }`, so the argument to `function() {}` is `undefined`.
6. We now execute `function() {}` proper. It never binds its argument, so the `undefined` is ignored. It doesn't return anything, so the call results in `undefined`.
7. Now we're done evaluating that expression! We'll set `that.baz` to the result, `undefined`.

Hopefully you see now that the parser misinterpreted your immediately-invoked function expression as, well, an argument to another anonymous function, immediately invoking *it*.

### How to prevent it?

As mentioned previously, parentheses are not the only way to unambiguously introduce an expression. In fact, when they're in the middle of the expression unintentionally, it can cause problems like this. We also mentioned assignments, but we don't want to assign something.

What's left? ***Unary operators.*** There's a few we can use. I like `!`, so we'll use that. Rather than using:

```
(function() {
    that.baz();
}());
```

We use:

```
!function() {
    that.baz();
}();
```

The `!` can only come at the start of an expression, so JavaScript starts parsing an expression. Only an expression can come after `!`, so the function is parsed as a function expression rather than a function definition. Because of precedence, the function is called first. It doesn't return anything, so it returns `undefined`. `undefined` is falsy, so `!` flips it and yields `true`. Since we never did anything with the result of this expression, the `true` is discarded. (It wouldn't have mattered if we returned a truthy value either; then `!` would have yielded `false` and that would be discarded. No matter what, it'll be discarded.)

### TLDR: Use a unary operator rather than parentheses for IIFEs.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> *Technically*, assignment is an expression, not a statement, but for our purposes it does not matter.
<sup>2</sup> With the exception of `return`, `continue`, `break`, and similar statements where it would confuse *much* more confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the very interesting discussion! I want to read it thoroughly and update my answer to make any needed corrections, but I'm out of time for tonight. Will take a closer look tomorrow, and in the meantime you get a grateful upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```
function Foo() {
    var that = this;
    { that.bar = function() {} }
    { that.baz = function() {} }

    (function() {
        that.baz();
    }());
}
new Foo;
```

Get it?

They are two statements. They require two endings.