# JavaScript semicolon after a function

Tags: javascript

I wonder the difference between two codes below in JavaScript, welcome answer.

Code 1:

```
function Add(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Code 2:

```
function Add(a,b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

Comment: The difference is that one has a semicolon after it and one doesn't.  The semicolon after the function is not needed.

Comment: thank all, I know the answer,there is this code style in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one is the standard method

Second one is not recommended.. Use the first method

Further reading - [Why should I use a semicolon after every function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/best-practice-for-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The second code contains an empty statement. You can add as many as you want.

```
function Add(a,b) {
    ;;;;;
    return a + b;;;;;;;
};;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. The `;` in the second example just creates an empty statement there.