# Add on click function on anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an anchor element which does not have any `class` or `id`. I want to add  a click handler to that anchor element. I tried in following way but no luck:

```
'<'a href="dosmthng" > do something</a>
var dosm = $('a[href^="dosmthng"]') //this works perfect it select anchor element
$(dosm).click(function() {
    alert(" click() called.");
});
```

The click function throws an error:

> VM556763:211 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document'.

Is there any better approach two achieve this?

P.S I can not change the HTML code in the file.

Comment: Could you post your actual HTML and JS code? What you've provided in the question is a bit of a mess. Assuming your markup is correct, what you have works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/L8Lqb2qt/. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Why not `$('a[href^="dosmthng"]').on('click',function(){...});`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao tried but it also giving error

Comment: is this correct ? '<'a href="dosmthng" > do something</a>

Comment: Is there a typo in '<'a href="dosmthng" >. I see an extra (').Alsoplease check if you have included jquery. This fiddle is working https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/g6Lu7ywr/

Comment: **[No it doesn't give error](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/x9nfLjog/1/)**

Comment: This line is not giving error you may be using `querySelector` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Looks like there's something dodgy in your html somewhere which is causing jquery not to load correctly.  Please read this [mcve] (emphasis on *verifiable* which this is not) and then debug your own code by starting yourself with minimal and building it up until you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1)Add click event in `document.ready`

2) Check anchor tag and remove unnecessary quotes from html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dosm = $('a[href^="dosmthng"]') //this works perfect it select anchor element

   $(dosm).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert( " click() called." );
   });
}); // doc-ready ends
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="dosmthng" > do something</a>
```

Comment: If this was the problem there wouldn't be an error, the click handler just wouldn't be attached at all.

Answer (score 0):

I see one potential issue.. you are missing a semi-colon at the end of the

```
var dosm = $('a[href^="dosmthng"]');
```

Comment: This is javascript, missing semi-colons have no impact.

Comment: Hmm, oh really? Then please tell me about this.. @freedomn-m ..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834642/why-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-every-function-in-javascript

Comment: They may not be required in some cases, but explain the undesired results of not putting one in

Comment: Not sure the relevance of that link as it's talking about function declarations, which this is not.   There are ***no** undesired results* of not putting a semi-colon on this statement.  It has no impact. Simply try it if you're still unconvinced.   Either way, this is not a valid *answer* to this question and completely off topic.