# setTimeout not working with Monq in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

While attempting to use `setTimeout` to perform rate limiting on a [`monq`](https://github.com/scttnlsn/monq) worker, why is the worker not being throttled?

`worker` does not wait for 10 seconds before executing `setTimeout()`. Why is this and how can we get it to delay the call to `foo()`?

```
var monq = require('monq')
var client = monq('localhost/mydb')
var worker = client.worker(['general'])
worker.register({
    test: function(params, callback) {
        try {
            setTimeout(foo(params, callback), 10000)
        } catch(err) {
            callback(err)
        }
    }
})

foo = function(params, callback) {
    console.log('Hello world')
    callback()
}
```

Comment: Minor point unrelated to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537632/should-i-use-semi-colons-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `setTimeout` expects a function reference. Instead, you're executing the function and passing the result to `setTimeout`.

Use:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    foo(params, callback);
}, 10000);
```

Also, the try/catch block is somewhat redundant there, because the call to `setTimeout` won't throw an exception. Instead, you would need to handle it inside `foo`.

Comment: Thanks! Will it also work if you move the try/catch box inside setTimeout, but outside of `foo`?

Comment: Yeah, that will do it.